# There something wrong somewhere but I dont know where is it

Tags: c

I don't know where I went wrong. I think there misplace or something but I not sure where is it. Its not my code but still I want to know where it goes wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

calculateArea(float t, float p, float a);
checkStatus(float a);

int main() {
  float t, p, a;

  printf("Please enter the height in cm: ");
  scanf("%f", &t);
  printf("\nPlease enter the length in cm: ");
  scanf("%f", &p);
  calculateArea(t, p, a);
  checkStatus(a);

  return 0;
}

int calculateArea(float t, float p, float a) {
  a = t * p;
  printf("The area of the box is: %.2f cm^2\n", a);
  return 0;
}

int checkStatus(float a) {
  if (a > 50) {
    printf("\nPass");
  } else {
    printf("\nDefect");

  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Stranger 234, Calling `calculateArea(t, p, a);` does not change or set the `a` in `main()`.  Save time.  Enable all warnings.  What complier are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is **calculateArea** function. It should takes only two parameter since your program only takes **float t** and **float p** from user as input. Your **calculateArea** should look like this.

```
float calculateArea(float t, float p) {
    float area = t * p;
    printf("The area of the box is: %.2f cm^2\n", area);
    return area;
}
```

The reason you need to return **area** is because **main** function still has no idea about **area** in **calculateArea** function. Keep in mind that you also have to change your function declaration to match what you have changed.
(In **calculateArea** function, I use **area** instead of **a** to avoid confusion)

Now since you return value from **calculateArea(float t, float p)**, you need to assign this value to **a**. At this point, your function calling part in **main** should look like this.

```
a = calculateArea(t, p);
checkStatus(a);
```

Now you are good to go. Hope this helps.

Edit: Change from `int calculateArea(float t, float p)`
to `float calculateArea(float t, float p)`. Thanks to [chux - Reinstate Monica](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2410359/chux-reinstate-monica) for correcting my answer.

Comment: More sense to return `float`: `float calculateArea(float t, float p)`.  Tip: enable all warnings.

Comment: This answer's `int calculateArea(float t, float p)` should be `float calculateArea(float t, float p)`.

Answer (score 0):

There are two common ways to achieve your goal. Firstly, you can use function returns which should be `float` instead of `int` and you need to assign to the `a` variable for calculating the area. So the function declaration of the calculating area must be like `float calculateArea(float t, float p)`. But, on the other hand, the function should return the calculated value to `a`. So the calculateArea process should be like this:

```
   float calculateArea(float t, float p) {
      float area = t * p;
      printf("The area of the box is: %.2f cm^2\n", a);
      return area;
    }
```

According to calculateArea function update `main` should be:

```
int main() {
  float t, p, a;

  printf("Please enter the height in cm: ");
  scanf("%f", &t);
  printf("\nPlease enter the length in cm: ");
  scanf("%f", &p);
  a = calculateArea(t, p);
  checkStatus(a);

  return 0;
}
```

Please be aware of how you declared function prototypes. The prototype should be updated too.

Answer (score -1):

```
int calculateArea(float t, float p, float a);
int checkStatus(float a);
```

Add the "int" may solve this problem?
I am a novice.